# PHP - Undefined Var - getting value from a MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, undefined, var

Im trying to make a function that retrieves a value from the db, but i`m getting the error var is undefined. I have read that you could set the php error level lower, but that looks like bad practice to me.

I have tried to pass de undefined var as param, I have tried to give it a standard value. but I dont seem to understand the concept here.

here is the code: $Playlist is undefined, something went wrong is printed to the screen

```
function returnPlaylistIndex(){

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
    if(!$con){
        mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbname limit 1");  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $PlayList = $row['playlistIndex'];
    }
mysql_close($con);
}
if(isset($Playlist)){
    echo $Playlist."<br />";
    return $Playlist;
} else {
    echo "something went wrong while quering";
}
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: In `SELECT * FROM dbname limit 1` is "dbname" just a typo for your example here? That should be the table you are selecting from.

Comment: Are you sure you really mean to select * from `dbname` which seems to be your database name, not a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code will actually never get around to querying the database because of this typo:

```
if(!$con){  // MEANT TO WRITE $con
```

Since the connection is always going to be good (otherwise there's a `die` in the previous line that would have stopped the script -- which actually makes the condition redundant) this condition will always fail and `$PlayList` will never be set.

Apart from that, note that you are using two separate styles of naming for the variable: `$PlayList` (camel case) and `$Playlist` (uppercase first letter only).

That said, I still do not understand why you would get an error message in this function since you are actually testing with `isset`. Can you provide the actual error and point out the line in which it occurs?

Comment: isset returns false, so it is printing out the error message he mentioned. (The echo line).

Comment: @Ilion: *"but i`m getting the error var is undefined"* => this is what I 'm referring to. It's obvious that he would get the "something went wrong" message (the question says so), but he's not asking about that.

Comment: I just figured his question was oddly worded and the final statement before his code sample explained what he was really receiving. Nothing else made sense otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `$PlayList` or `$Playlist`, but not mixed.

Variables are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

something seems wrong with :

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbname limit 1");
```

`dbname` should be `table` name please check. Make sure your query is returning results try to run at console.

and also initilize  `$PlayList` array before while loop :

like : `$PlayList=array();`

php variables are case-sensitive. Please check they should be in same case.

```
if(isset($PlayList)){
    echo $PlayList."<br />";
    return $PlayList;
} else {
    echo "something went wrong while quering";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, except one thing:

```
if(isset($PlayList)){
    echo $PlayList."<br />";
    return $PlayList;
} else {
    echo "something went wrong while quering";
}
```

note that $PlayList and $Playlist are not same :)

Answer (score 0):

Database selection can be done only if DB connection is effective:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
if($con !== FALSE) {
  mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case-sensitive about variable's names, but not about function/method names.

Because of that PHP "see" `$PlayList` and `$Playlist` as 2 diff vars.

Also, check if the $result is valid resource:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name limit 1");
if( $result )
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```